# Need to modify KDEInit entry

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, kde-plasma

I'm running mint 17.2 kde.

I installed intellij CE by running idea.sh in ~/Downloads/

Then I moved intellij to /usr/lib/. Now I get this when I try to open intellij from the Application Launcher:

`KDEInit could not launch '/home/******/Downloads/idea-IC-143.1821.5/bin/idea.sh'`

I know I could just move it back, but I would really prefer to point Application Launcher in the right direction.

I've already checked out .kde/share/config and didn't find any mention of idea.sh, jetbrains, or intellij that seemed like a relevant entry.

Is there somewhere else that Application Launcher entries are saved? Is it possible to remove entries then add new ones from the application itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up grepping through my entire home directory for files that used the full path posted in the error message.

`grep -rnw '/home/******/' -e ".*/home/******/Downloads/idea-IC-143.1821.5/bin/idea.sh.*"`

This returned `jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop` in my .gnome, .kde, and .local directories, all of which I modified. I could launch intellij from the Application Launcher after this.